What airplane model does this toy fighter jet represent?

I couldn't figure out what this plane could be, I was thinking of a Eurofighter Typhoon but then I realised that the Typhoon has only one vertical stabilizer.

These sort of toys are often based on,  but not exactly the same as,  real models.

BTW the white -2 is a Shenyang J-35. The single-engine one next to it is F35. The small black one on the far side is MIG-29. All of these models changed the V tail to conventional straight tail probably because V tail won't come out of injection molding.

Your "EJECTION PLANE 22-3" most closely resembles a Chengdu J-20. Its proportions are more or less correct, and has the distinctive forward-sweep of the air intakes.
The tailplanes need to be canted outwards, and the nose a little pointier (problematic on a child's toy); otherwise it's a fair approximation.

source
(Both the Typhoon and the J-20 are two-engined aircraft, which you can tell by the two nozzles at the rear of both types.)

Typhoon does have two engines (or at least exhaust ducts), but only one vertical stabilizer.
